# Schema registry maven plugin unable to execute test-compatibility with new subjects

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Is there a way to execute the `schema-registry:test-compatibility` goal ([ref](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html#schema-registry-test-compatibility)) with subjects that I haven't registered yet but are in my local dev environment?

We're using protobuf.

When I try to run the goal above I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Could not parse Protobuf schema
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject '[SUBJECT NAME].proto' not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getByVersion (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:502)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.AbstractSchemaProvider.resolveReferences (AbstractSchemaProvider.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.AbstractSchemaProvider.resolveReferences (AbstractSchemaProvider.java:52)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaProvider.parseSchemaOrElseThrow (ProtobufSchemaProvider.java:41)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:123)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:286)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (SchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.processSubject (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:120)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.execute (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject '[SUBJECT NAME].proto' not found.; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest (RestService.java:335)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest (RestService.java:408)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getVersion (RestService.java:959)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getVersion (RestService.java:943)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByVersionFromRegistry (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:544)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByVersion (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:523)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getByVersion (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:500)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.AbstractSchemaProvider.resolveReferences (AbstractSchemaProvider.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.AbstractSchemaProvider.resolveReferences (AbstractSchemaProvider.java:52)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaProvider.parseSchemaOrElseThrow (ProtobufSchemaProvider.java:41)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.SchemaProvider.parseSchema (SchemaProvider.java:123)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:286)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.parseSchema (SchemaRegistryClient.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.processSubject (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:120)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.maven.UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.execute (UploadSchemaRegistryMojo.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] Schema for [SUBJECT NAME].proto could not be parsed.
```

All other subjects run fine. I'd like to add this compatibility check in the CI pipeline. That's also the reason we can't use the `schema-registry:test-local-compatibility`.

Comment: If you want to test against local files or against a subject that does not exist, then you cannot use `test-compatibility`, as that will make an HTTP request to the registry.

Comment: I see. For now I'm registering the new subject manually through the API/cli and then run the check in the pipeline. But are you aware of any workarounds to automate the compatibility checks and avoid the manual process?

Comment: What's the exact issue with test-local-compatibility? That's what it was made for https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html#schema-registry-test-local-compatibility There should be no difference between your CI system and external setup. You'll need to keep a reference to your previous schema files in your build process, then only selectively register the most recent, for example

Comment: That's a good point. I've tried that along with the `:download` goal in order to fetch locally all schemas and then copy only the new files. And now the build is failing as not compatible, but the change I've made is definitely compatible (added only a new field). I now think the issue is because all subjects in SR are normalized when were added so the local versions seem modified

Comment: Not sure about that, but I know when I used Kafka Connect, it would add `connect.meta.data` and some extra doc comments within the Avro schemas that we'd often run into compatibility issues with, but I think the logic in the Registry has solved some of those bugs in the meantime